# Trouble understanding differential forms. A basic question: what does $w \times dw$ mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, hodge-theory

After reading [1] and [2] I (kind of) understand what differential forms are, but  I am still having trouble understanding the following argument from [3,Lem.4.2]:

Let $\mathbb{T^3_n}$ be the 3-dimensional torus with period $2\pi n$ (meaning $\mathbb{T^3_n} \simeq [-\pi n, \pi n]^3$). And let $v \in H^1(\mathbb{T_n^3,\mathbb{C}})$ satisfy $\vert v \vert \geq \frac{1}{2}$ on $\mathbb{T_n^3}$.

We then may write $v= \vert v \vert w$ with $\vert w \vert = 1$. This seams clear.

Let $dw$ denote the differential form induced by $w$. The author then goes on to say that $d(w \times dw)=0$ and we therefore can perform the Hodge-de-Rham decomposition of $w \times dw$.

My (first basic) questions are

> a) What is $w \times dw$ supposed to be? I couldn't find this notation for differential forms anywhere.
>
> b) What is a good source to find information about the Hodge-de-Rham decomposition?

---

[1] http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/diffforms.pdf

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form

[3] Béthuel, F., P. Gravejat und J. C. Saut: Travelling waves for the Gross-
Pitaevskii equation. II. Comm. Math. Phys., 285(2):567–651, 2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), in certain traditions the symbol $\times$ is used (in the sense of the cross product of multivariable calculus) interchangeably with $\wedge$ for the wedge product.

For (b), if you just want to know what it is, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_decomposition#Hodge_decomposition) is a good place to start. The most general version of the Hodge-de-Rham decomposition is quite complicated (stated for elliptic complexes in general), for the version that you seem to care about, [random googling turns up this document](http://www.nikno.de/sites/default/files/hodge.pdf) which may be an okay place to start. [Here's some lecture notes](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/YM-lectures/lecture5.pdf) which gives the theory modulo analytical details.

It is hard to recommend a textbook for this, because most Hodge theory books deal with Kahler manifolds which is a bit stronger than what you need (as it appears). The best source I know (indeed, the one I would personally go to) is Morita's *Geometry of Differential Forms* [(Google books link)](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Geometry_of_differential_forms.html?id=5N33Of2RzjsC&redir_esc=y) where the Hodge decomposition is treated in Chapter 4. But be aware that his notation and language may be a bit different from the two resources that you linked to, so you may have to start mostly from the beginning of the book to really "get" it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I orderd Morita's book at the library. But if $\times$ does denote the wedge product, why is Béthuel sometimes using $\times$ and sometimes $\wedge$? And still: what does $w \times dw$ mean? $dw$ is a 1-Form and $w$ is a function...

Comment: If $w$ is just a function, then $\times = \wedge = \cdot$ is just the usual multiplication operator.... a scalar function is treated in the graded hierarchy of differential forms as a "0-form".

Comment: Thank you! This is much appreciated!